# Differential equation separate the variables

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

I have to find all solutions to the following differential equation: $$\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = t \sin(x).$$ I know I can use the technique of separation by variables, but I'm having some trouble. This is where I am so far:

Let $g(x) = \sin(x)$ and $h(t) = t$. Then $\frac{\text{d}x}{\text{d}t} = g(x)h(t)$. Let $$G(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \frac{1}{\sin(x)} \text{d} x \qquad \text{and}\qquad H(t) = \int_{t_0}^t t \,\text{d}t.$$ Then, $$G(x) = \int_{x_0}^x \csc(x) \,\text{d}x = -\ln |\csc(x) + \cot(x)| \Big|_{x_0}^x \qquad \text{and} \qquad H(t) = \frac{t^2 - t_0^2}{2}.$$

I know that now $x(t) = G^{-1}(H(t))$, but I have no idea how to compute $G^{-1}$, since the expression for $G$ seems complicated, which makes me think I'm on the wrong track with this problem.

Comment: Often times such equations define functions implicitly and many times that's the best you can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several forms of the general antiderivative for $\csc x$. One more amenable to inversion is
$$\int \csc x\, \text{d}x = \log \tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) + C,$$ which is valid on the interval, say, $(0, \pi)$. With this in hand (and a little care), one can write $G^{-1}$ and hence a (nearly general) solution $x(t)$.

Don't forget to include the solutions implicitly discarded when rearranging, namely those for which $\sin x = 0$!

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I needed...

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad it was helpful.

Comment: By the way, you can derive the alternate form I posted from the usual form in the question using the half-angle identity for tangent: $\csc x + \cot x = \frac{1}{\sin x} + \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{1 + \cos x}{\sin x} = \frac{1}{\tan \frac{x}{2}}$.